# Check whether Kafka topic has new messages without consuming

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a scenario where there a pair of topics in a Spring Boot project (a snapshot and a delta topics), which should be consumed in accordance with the following rules:

1. The delta topic is listened and consumed all the time that microservise works on.
2. If the shapshot topic contains new messages, a delta topic consumer must be stopped, and the snapshot topic consumer should read that new messages (consumers must not work in parralel since they insert or update rows to the same table in Postgres DB, and there is no guarantee, that a transaction from the snapshot topic consumer will insert or update its rows before a transaction of the delta topic.

So, is there a way only to check periodically (without consuming) that the snapshot topic has new messages? Then I could stop a delta consumer container manually, start a snapshot consumer container, shut it down after completion, and start the delta consumer container again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `KafkaConsumer` (from the consumer factory) using the snapshot topic's listener's `group.id`; then

- `consumer.committed(setOfTopics, someDuration);`
- `consumer.endOffsets(setOfTopics, someDuration);`
- `consumer.close(someDuration);`

The first gets the offset of the next record that will be consumed from each partition. The second gets the (current) last offset.

If any end offset is greater than, or equal to, the committed offset, stop the delta container; start the snapshot container. Use idle container detection to determine when the snapshot listener is done.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

Then stop the snapshot container and start the delta container.

You can stop/start containers (by `id`) using the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean provided by the framework.

Comment: Do I uderstand you correct, that you suggest to calculate a snapshot topic lag periodically (via Spring's @Scheduled for example) and start/stop containers depeding on the lag's value?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stopping and starting consumers you can have only one consumer which is consuming messages from both the topics with this approach you can process messages one by one.